# How to implement lift method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to move my function `NEW_FRAME` in front of the `Frame` for the root window so that old frame and the other widget in it will be behind for the function `NEW_FRAME` to only display its widget. So I searched and discovered that `tkinter` has `lift` method to achieve that but I can't implement it correctly, have tried positioning it at different places inside the function.

this link :[explanation of the lift method with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855906/tkinter-lift-and-lower-methods-with-grid-layout)

[image: how my frames is stacking on each other]

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x600")

welcome = Frame(root, bg="yellow")
welcome.pack( fill=BOTH, expand=True)

label = Label(welcome, text="welcome bro to page one")
label.grid(row=45, column=50)

b = Label(welcome, text="you can select menu bar to switch page")
b.grid(row=100, column=500)


def NEWS_Frame():
    new = Frame(root, bg="red")
    new.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    l1 = Label(new, text="Have been waiting for")
    l1.grid(row=49, column=80)

    l2 = Label(new, text="hello dude how be things")
    l2.grid(row=0, column=0)

    new.lift()  # have position it to lift the new frame to the top of Frame

# menu bar start here

MAIN_MENU = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=MAIN_MENU)


File_menu = Menu(MAIN_MENU)
MAIN_MENU.add_cascade(label="NEW PAGE", menu=File_menu, underline=0)
File_menu.add_command(label="NEWS", command=NEWS_Frame)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Is it this verifiable and minimal this the code am working with

Comment: You can't put a frame _over_ another frame using `pack`. It is literally for stacking widgets horizontally and vertically, whereas the problem requires the 3rd dimension

Comment: Your code isn't specific to the problem you're having.

Comment: It is , please run the code see what am talking about

Comment: It been stack on each other when I click on the NEWS button under menu bar, and also the the widget in the old root frame still displays

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should *only* include *the least* amount of code as possible to reproduce the specific issue. The code below reproduces exactly the behavior you're having an issue with, but *nothing* more:

```
import tkinter as tk


def swap():
    button2.pack()
    button2.lift()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 2", command=swap)
    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 1")
    button1.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**A workaround using [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):**

You *can't* put widgets over another widget using `pack`. `pack` is literally for stacking in the 2-d, as in it is for stacking horizontally or vertically but *not* for piling widgets in the depth dimension. However, a *bad* workaround would be to simply hide the widget while displaying the other, which doesn't require `lift` at all.

In the below code each time `swap` is called it hides one button while displaying the other:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def swap():
    global is_button1_lifted
    if is_button1_lifted:
        button1.pack_forget()
        button2.pack()
    else:
        button2.pack_forget()
        button1.pack()
    is_button1_lifted = not is_button1_lifted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    is_button1_lifted = True
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 2", command=swap)
    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 1", command=swap)
    swap()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**Answer using [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm):**

This *is* the way of using [`lift`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lift-method) in the OP's case. The way this works is that both widgets displayed in *the same* node of a grid. The widget `lift` method is used on simply comes *over* the other(s).

In the below example both buttons are displayed, while one(`button2` in this case) simply blocks the other by being in front of the other. When the `lift` is called it simply makes its object come to the front:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def swap():
    global is_button1_lifted
    if is_button1_lifted:
        button2.lift()
    else:
        button1.lift()
    is_button1_lifted = not is_button1_lifted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    is_button1_lifted = False
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 2", command=swap)
    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 1", command=swap)
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    button2.grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**Answer using [`place`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm):**

This works almost the same way as the answer with `grid`, `place` simply has a more direct layout control:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def swap():
    global is_button1_lifted
    if is_button1_lifted:
        button2.lift()
    else:
        button1.lift()
    is_button1_lifted = not is_button1_lifted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    is_button1_lifted = False
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 2", command=swap)
    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Swap with button 1", command=swap)
    button1.place(x=23, y=87)
    button2.place(x=23, y=87)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`lift` moves widgets in the Z axis, `pack` arranges widgets in the X and Y axis. `lift` is incapable of changing the ordering of widget arranged with `pack`